# Push a policy to Java clients?

Tags: java, group-policy, administration

This question came up when I was attempting to set the list of SSL/TLS cipher suites in a Java program. In Java, its quite painful at times to do simple things like set the list of ciphers because `SSLSocketFactory` does *not* have `setEnabledCipherSuites`.

According to the fellow I ask Java questions, a Java Admin configures their Java installation with things like cipher lists and algorithms. I'm aware Novell's eDirectory has ConsoleOne to create, modify and push policies; and Microsoft's Active Directory has Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC) to create, modify and push policies.

What tool does a Java Admin use to create, modify and push policies to the 5 or 6 workstations in my home network? Or have the clients pull the policy? For example, how would I enable the cipher suites `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` or `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256`; or remove suites with RC4 ciphers like `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5` and `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA`?